# how to get synonyms list from ms word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-automation

In word automation, how to get synonyms list through ms word using c# language. please advice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SynonymInfo Object

Refer this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178951.aspx

Comment: is it only available for VB ?